# Way to optimize comparator

Tags: java, comparator

Is there any way to order people name's by surname1, if not, surname2, if not, name, more efficiently than this?
This is too slow, thanks!

```
        Collections.sort(lResult, new java.util.Comparator<Map>() {
           public int compare(Map m1, Map m2) {
               
               int lResult;            
               String i1= (String)m1.get("surname1");
               String i2= (String)m2.get("surname1");
               if((i1 == null) || (i2==null)) {lResult = 0;}
               else {lResult = i1.compareTo(i2);}
    
               if (lResult == 0) {                  
                    String t1= (String)m1.get("surname2");
                    String t2= (String)m2.get("surname2");
                    if((t1 == null) || (t2==null)) {lResult = 0;}
                    else {lResult = t1.compareTo(t2);}
                    
                }  
               
               if (lResult == 0) {
                    String x1= (String)m1.get("name");
                    String x2= (String)m2.get("name "); 
                    if((x1 == null) || (x2==null)) {lResult = 0;}
                    else {lResult = x1.compareTo(x2);}
                }  
                return lResult;
           }
        });
```

Comment: I highly doubt this is _too slow_. Do you mean this code is too long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Irrespective of speed, your comparator isn't correct.

The only things which should be considered equal are, well, equal things. You would currently consider `null` to be equal to `"non-null"`, and so that would lead to odd behavior.

Specifically, what you seem to be doing is comparing the first pair of corresponding values which are both non-null. This violates the transitivity requirement of Comparator implementations. Consider, for example:

```
A = {"surname1": "A",  "surname2", null, "name": "A"}
B = {"surname1": null, "surname2", "B",  "name": "B"}
C = {"surname1": "A",  "surname2", "C",  "name": null}
```

According to your comparator, `A < B` and `B < C`. However, `A == C`, thus making it an invalid comparator.

The easiest way to write this Comparator - correctly - would be something like:

```
nullsLast(comparing(m -> (String) m.get("surname1")))
    .thenComparing(nullsLast(comparing(m -> (String) m.get("surname2"))))
    .thenComparing(nullsLast(comparing(m -> (String) m.get("name"))));
```

where `nullsLast` and `comparing` are methods from `Comparator`. (`nullsFirst` can be used instead, if that's how you'd prefer to handle nulls).

With pre-Java 8, you can write an equivalent comparison using a helper method:

```
public int compare(Map m1, Map m2) {
  int lResult;

  lResult = compare(m1, m2, "surname1");
  if (lResult != 0) return lResult;

  lResult = compare(m1, m2, "surname2");
  if (lResult != 0) return lResult;

  return compare(m1, m2, "name");
}

private int compare(Map m1, Map m2, String key) {
  String v1= (String)m1.get(key);
  String v2= (String)m2.get(key);
  if (v1 != null && v2 != null) {
    return v1.compareTo(v2);
  }
  return Boolean.compare(v1 != null, v2 != null);
}
```

Or use something like Guava's `ComparisonChain`.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't mention i'm using Java 6, i think i cannot do that.

Comment: The method compare(boolean, boolean) is undefined for the type Boolean. I think i can't put return Boolean.compare

Comment: @Martinez then use `(v1 != null) == (v2 != null) ? 0 : (v1 != null) ? -1 : 1`. Or `Boolean.valueOf(v1 != null).compareTo(Boolean.valueOf(v2 != null))`. Even if you are using ancient versions of Java, it doesn't stop you [reading the docs of more recent versions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Boolean.html).